# More explicitly, what is $\left(p_n\right)_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ in this paper's context

Tags: polynomials, terminology

I'm reading [this paper](http://org.uib.no/hcaa/1001.4695.pdf) and on page 3 between just prior to their mentioning of $\left(2\right)$ they state the following:

> ...if there is a sequence of polynomials
>   $\left(p_n\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of fixed degree such that...

What do they mean, more explicitly, by this?

Thank you for your time,

Answer (score 0):

It's a sequence of polynomials with fixed degree. For example $p_1=x^3+x$, $p_2=x^3$, $p_3=x^3-x$...

Comment: I see, thanks! So it will be an indexed sequence of fixed-degree polynomials?

Comment: Yup. Have you seen sequences before?

Comment: I have, I'm just getting my bearings on them I suppose. I read about them in a book just yesterday, so I'd consider myself a beginner.

Comment: Another (and explicit) example of this would be the sequence $\{p_n(x)=x^2-n\}$.  Another example would be 'the sequences of cubic polynomials whose roots are the $n$th, $(n+1)$st and $(n+2)$nd prime numbers'.